# How to use sprite in android (Game )

Tags: android

I am new to android. How do I detect collision between two objects? Is possible to use sprites, like in j2me?

In j2me:

```
Sprite s =new Sprite(img,img.getWidth/5,img.getHeight)
s.nextFrame();
s.move(5,0);

Sprite s1 =new Sprite(img1,img1.getWidth/5,img1.getHeight)
s1.nextFrame();
s1.move(-5,0)
if(s1.collidesWith(s,true))
{
     /* ... */
}
```

How do I do this in Android?

Comment: A sprite is nothing more than a image, which has coordinates where it is painted. I don't know if there's any related class, but detecting a collision using rectangles is very easy, you can do it yourself.

Comment: Then how to detect collision in android. Any sample example ?

Comment: I find a solution. I am using Andengine for game developing

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to do it yourself, then the easiest way probably is to use the Rect class, or the RectF in case you need floats:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RectF.html

Tipically, you would use collision detection with the rectangles that contains your images. It can be done with other shapes, but it is more complex. You can use the `intersect(Rect)` methods to detect intersections. Also dont forget to check for inclusion, which is this case:

```
    ------------
    |          |
    |  -----   |
    |  |   |   |
    |  -----   |
    |          |
    ------------
```

using the `contains(Rect)` method. This is necessary in case your sprites are moving so fast that the intersection method doesnt detect anything (in a game loop iteration they are not colliding, and in the inmmediate next iteration they are one inside another). In this case, you'll have to check both two colliding sprites against each other. For intersection, it is enough to do it with one:

```
    static boolean collide(Rect r1, Rect r2){
        if(r1.intersect(r2) || r1.contains(r2) || r2.contains(r1)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

There are excellent tutorials on 2D games on the net, and also a lot of source code available to learn, including Android's. It is always worth to have a look at these.